# Outlook folder structure Template

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Having a lot of different customers and a lot of different areas to work with makes it trivial to have your mail folders in order. Everytime I get a new Project / Customer I want to add a certain Folder Structure in my "Customer" / "Project" sub directory.

It might look like this:

```
Customer_name/
    Bugs
    Documents
    Important
    Support/
        Done
```

And as it is today, I have to manually add these manually, which is harsh when you have a lot of it going on and each sub directory under the customer_name directory needs to have "display all items" since it's important to me to see all Items in Bugs / Support / Important.

Makes my life easier.

So, Is it possible to Automize the process somehow? Macro? Folder Templates?

What are my options?

**Edit**

I have something like this set up at the moment:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNameSpace.PickFolder
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Quit
End If
Set objFolders = objFolder.Folders
customer = InputBox("Enter Customer Name:")
Set objCustomerFolders = objFolders.Add(customer).Folders
objCustomerFolders.Add("Bugs")
objCustomerFolders.Add("Documents")
objCustomerFolders.Add("Important")
Set objSupportFolders = objCustomerFolders.Add("Support").Folders
objSupportFolders.Add("Done")
```

But this doesn't set the Properties on each folder.

So a follow up question would be, do I have to solve this with programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNameSpace.PickFolder
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Quit
End If
Set objFolders = objFolder.Folders
customer = InputBox("Enter Customer Name:")
Set objCustomerFolders = objFolders.Add(customer).Folders
objCustomerFolders.Add("Bugs")
objCustomerFolders.Add("Documents")
objCustomerFolders.Add("Important")
Set objSupportFolders = objCustomerFolders.Add("Support").Folders
objSupportFolders.Add("Done")
```

This will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an empty version of the folder structure you want.
Then when you get a new project, right click drag this "template" to where you want it, and choose "copy" when you let go.

This will create an empty copy of the folder and all it's subfolders.

If this copy is in the same folder as the original empty one, the top level will get renamed with an appended number, but this probably won't matter since you will be renaming it to your customer / project anyway.

I know it's not a "click a button" solution, but it's a simple drag and drop each time and job done.

Comment: This means that in my folder I need to have an empty folder structure in the way, sorry but this is not an option for me.